# Drop down menu does woking

Tags: html, css

i am designing a template for my academic purpose. HTML structure for my navigation bar is given below.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="nav">
            <div id="nav_wrapper">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li>
                    <a href="#">Events</a>
                     <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Coding</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Quiz</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li><li>
                    <a href="#">About Us</a></li><li>
                    <a href="#">Contact US</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>      
        </div>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>My First Website</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="content">aaf
        </div>
        <div id="footer">afaf
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and i write style.css as follows

```
  body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 18;
}
#nav{
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
#nav_wrapper{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
#nav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 50px;
}
#nav ul ul li{
    display:block; 
    background-color: red;
}
#nav ul ul{
    display: none;
}
#nav ul li :hover ul{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
#nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav ul li :hover{
    background-color: #FF99FF;
    color: black;
}
```

My problem is the drop down menu does not appear as i hover on the event item. I need help to fix it.

Comment: Try removing the space before `:hover` or using the `>` parent operator instead of the whitespace operators in your selectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you should remove the blankspace between li and :hover. It worked for me after that.

```
#nav ul li:hover ul{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

And also here

```
#nav ul li:hover{
  background-color: #FF99FF;
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 body{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
font-size: 18;
}
#nav{
background-color: black;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
}
#nav_wrapper{
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
}
#nav ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
}
#nav ul li{
display: inline-block;
line-height: 50px;
}
#nav ul ul li{
display:block; 
background-color: red;
}
#nav ul ul{
display: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul{
display: block;
position: absolute;
}
#nav ul li a{
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
display: block;
width: 120px;
text-align: center;
}
#nav ul li :hover{
background-color: #FF99FF;
color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="nav">
        <div id="nav_wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li>
                <a href="#">Events</a>
                 <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Coding</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Quiz</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li><li>
                <a href="#">About Us</a></li><li>
                <a href="#">Contact US</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>      
    </div>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>My First Website</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content">aaf
    </div>
    <div id="footer">afaf
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this one as per your need:

https://jsfiddle.net/k2va9ngo/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="drop-nav">
  <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Content Management</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Joomla</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Drupal</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">WordPress</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Concrete 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">General Inquiries</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ask me a Question</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
 ul {list-style: none;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;}
  ul li {display: block;position: relative;float: left;border:1px solid #000}
  li ul {display: none;}
  ul li a {display: block;background: #000;padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;text-decoration: none;
           white-space: nowrap;color: #fff;}
  ul li a:hover {background: #f00;}
  li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute;}
  li:hover li {float: none;}
  li:hover a {background: #f00;}
  li:hover li a:hover {background: #000;}
  #drop-nav li ul li {border-top: 0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav ul ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul{
    background-color: #FF99FF;
    color: black;
    display:block;
}
```

You'll see I added a position absolute to the #nav ul ul.
I also got rid of the space you had in #nav ul li: hover and added the ul after hover. You need to then set display block to show that nested ul.

Without setting that ul ul position to absolute, your parent ul will get pushed down when your drop down appears. Delete it and see what I mean.